# Unpack Requires A String Argument of Length: Windows Issue?

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I am receiving the error above where it asking me for a string length of 4 as I am trying to unpack a float from a binary file. My code runs perfectly fine on my Mac, however it falls short on Windows. The code is as follows:

```
for i in range (0,elec_array.nb_chan):

    elec_array.chan[i].x = struct.unpack('f',f.read(4))[0]
    elec_array.chan[i].y = struct.unpack('f',f.read(4))[0]
```

The problem occurs at `elec_array.chan[i].x` line. It does not occur immediately however, it will go through a few iterations in the loop first, and then finally give the error that a string of length 4 is required. Again, the code works perfectly fine on Mac, but for some reason stops working on my Windows 7 PC. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to open the file in binary mode. In text mode, a `0x0d` `0x0a` sequence gets shortened to `0x0a` and your file will be the wrong size.

Comment: @user1217248, the usual way of thanking someone on StackOverflow is to hit the up-arrow to the left of the answer, then select the most correct answer and hit the checkmark underneath it.

Comment: Ah, forgive me for not knowing how to use this here stack overflow yet. I have put the checkmark for providing the right answer, unfortunately I need more rep before I can give out rep.

Comment: @user1217248, you're supposed to be able to vote on answers to your own questions. Is that not working for you?

Comment: Thank You! I've been trying to figure this out all day. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, do the `read()` separately; it's I/O so it can, as you've just learned, fail.

To debug, print the data and the length of the data as you read it, this will help you understand what's going wrong.

It's hard to be more specific without seeing the file, and the surrounding code. Are you opening the file in binary mode?

Comment: As the other user stated, I failed to open in binary mode, which is something you also suggested. Thanks for the help!